# Filtering on date range in CakePHP controller

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a Subtask and a Horse model.

Horse hasMany Subtask.

Subtask has a date associated with it.  It is a MYSQL date object, NOT a datetime.

In my View/Horse/view.ctp, I want to only print out subtasks that are between a given date range, and I am having difficulty doing that.  I can pass in subtasks using regular filtering, in my controller method:

```
    $this->set('incomplete_subtasks', $this->Subtask->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                'and' => array(
                    'completed ' => 0,
                    'Subtask.horse_id ' => $id)))));
```

I am trying to filter on a date range using this:

```
$this->set('incomplete_subtasks', $this->Subtask->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                'and' => array(
                    'completed ' => 0,
                    'Subtask.horse_id ' => $id,
                    'Subtask.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                    date(Y-m-d),
                    date(Y-m-d, strtotime('+1 week'))

                    )
                )
            )
            )));
```

I get this error in horse/view:

`Notice (8): Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' [APP/Controller/HorsesController.php, line 56]`

I get that error for every constant I am using in the expression- there are six of them total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "constant" as I can't see any constants in your code, I'm guessing it's because you haven't wrapped `Y-m-d` in quotes (so PHP assumes they are constants).

Firstly, try wrapping them in quotes:

```
'Subtask.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
    date('Y-m-d'),
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'))
)
```

Failing that, you should do a simple `<=` and `>=` for your dates instead, and the `and` key of your conditions isn't necessary here (unless there are other array keys you're omitting in your code).

Try this:

```
$this->set('incomplete_subtasks', $this->Subtask->find('all', array('conditions' => 
    array(
        'completed ' => 0,
        'Subtask.horse_id ' => $id,
        'Subtask.date >=' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'Subtask.date <=' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'))
    )
)));
```